# Are there any small battery powered 360 degree cameras capable of a native "google cardboard" format output over HDMI connection?

Tags: video, camera, live

The question is really part #2 of the following project:

I'm looking into

1. mounting a 360 degree camera to a drone to get a view like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZ02-Qenso)
2. camera captures and can output the video like a webcam in "google cardboard" format to a transmitter with a HDMI port
3. transmit the video to the ground using a HDMI input from the drone to the ground like a regular HD feed
4. allow a user to watch the feed from the receiver on the ground using google cardboard
5. when the user turns his head, the video should track the head movements

This is all do-able if you record and post process but I haven't seen anyone do it for a live stream. The closest would be the [TEDxAMSTERDAM](http://tedx.amsterdam/2014/11/virtual-front-row-seat/) which utilised a bunch of camera outputs to stitch one big 360 degree output and live stream that.

I figured if you already had the output of the camera in "google cardboard" format, you could cut the post-processing out and serve it live. Are there any such camera